# Invalid buffer error in SurfaceFlinger when trying to take picture on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to simulate taking a picture with the Android emulator. The moment I press the button which takes the picture LogCat begins showing the following error over and over again:

> ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(58): LayerBuffer::BufferSource::postBuffer() invalid buffer (offset=1739520, size=111650, heap-size=151552

Any ideas on what it means and how it can be fixed? The relevant code is below:

```
public void takePicture(final ImageView imageView) {
    Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() {         
        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
            Log.d(null, "onShutter called");
            setIsShutterActivated(true);
        }
    };

    Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {         
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Log.d(null, "onPictureTaken called");
            setIsShutterActivated(false);
            Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
        }
    };

    mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, pictureCallback);
}
```